# Find if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})+\cos(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln^3(n)}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> Find if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})+\cos(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln^3(n)}$ converges

I proved that the function is monotonic so it's the same as $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})+\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{\ln^3(x)}dx$

Using taylor we have $\sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}x+o(\frac{1}{x^2}), \cos(\frac{1}{x})=1+o(\frac{1}{x}),$

So I want to say that using limit convergence test we can say it converges iff $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}+1}{\ln^3(x)}dx$ converges. I wasn't sure about how to show  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}x+o(\frac{1}{x^2})+1+o(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}+1}$=1 (which i think is true, isn't it? kinda confusing) for the limit test, So i'd like help with this specifically.

and then I think $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}+1}{\ln^3(x)}dx$ = $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{1+x}{x\ln^3(x)}dx$ doesn't converge because if we break it up, we get one converging integral and one diverging, but I'm not sure if we can use limit arithmetics here, would like clarification.

P.S, I know the answer is it doesn't converge, and also there's a nice solution with a theorem that shows for monotonic converging to 0 $a_n$ that $\sum_1^{\infty} a_n$ converges iff $\sum_1^{\infty} 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges, in case anyone is interested. But I'd like help with my solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sum \frac {\sin (\frac 1 n)} {\ln^{3}}$ is convergent since $0 \leq \sin (\frac 1 n) \leq \frac1 n$ and the integral test  can be applied to $\sum \frac 1 {n\ln ^{3}n}$.

$\sum \frac {\cos (\frac 1 n)} {\ln^{3}n}$ is divergent because $\cos (\frac 1 n) \geq \frac 1  2$ for $n$ sufficiently large and $\sum \frac 1 {\ln^{3} n} $ is divergent. Hence the given series is divergent.